# Bootstrap tabs, jquery .tab function, open particular tab on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, typeerror

I am using bootstrap 3 in an application.
My issue right now is with loading particular tabs on page load from hash sign in the url. I am using the following Javascript code to do so.

However inside the if(hash) the function call to .tab gives:

> TypeError: $(...).tab is not a function.

I'm pretty convinced that this is due to jQuery conflicts, but I need help with solving it. The application has the following scripts included. I have never worked with jQuery before.

The application has a lot of features in place which don't work if i exclude the stuff below **bootstap.min.js** and the bootsrap scripts don't work if i exclude **jquery.min.js** from above.

If i take **jquery.min.js** out, and move up **jquery-latest.min.js** then the original features work and so seam the tabs as i can see the url change. However, all the bootstrap script stops working so the tabs dont actually change and the rest of the bootstrap features dont work as well.

Does anybody have some guidance on priority one getting the load tabs to work and priority two cleaning this include mess?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

          // Javascript to enable link to tab
        var hash = document.location.hash;
        var prefix = "tab_";
        if (hash) {
            $('.nav-tabs a[href='+hash.replace(prefix,"")+']').tab('show');
        } 

        // Change hash for page-reload
        $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
            window.location.hash = e.target.hash.replace("#", "#" + prefix);
        });
    });
```

---

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="/scripts/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.jeditable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.jeditable.masked.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.maskedinput-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/date.format.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.floatThead.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/PatientSearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: What is `jquery-latest.min.js`? It looks like jQuery library but you are also loading jQuery from the Google CDN?

Comment: @DavidG If i take jquery-latest.min.js out, the document ready functions dont get executed.